# Json pretty print fails

Tags: android, json

I have this code with Android API Level 15

```
        JSONArray l = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject a = new JSONObject();
        a.put("a", "a");
        a.put("b", "a");
        a.put("c", "d");
        l.put(a);
        a = new JSONObject();
        a.put("d", "a");
        a.put("g", "3");
        l.put(a);

        Log.d(TAG, l.toString(3));
        Log.d(TAG, l.toString());
```

and the output is this

```
DEBUG   test    [
DEBUG   test       {
DEBUG   test          "b": "a",
DEBUG   test          "c": "d",
DEBUG   test          "a": "a"
DEBUG   test       },
DEBUG   test          "g": "3",
DEBUG   test          "d": "a"
DEBUG   test       }
DEBUG   test    ]
DEBUG   test    [{"b":"a","c":"d","a":"a"},{"g":"3","d":"a"}]
```

The pretty print output lacks an opening { for the 2nd JSONObject.
Is this a known bug ?

(When using Gson happens the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It's working well for me, I'm using Intellij:

```
10-15 14:18:43.433: DEBUG/it.enrichman.myapp(4470): [
        {
        "b": "a",
        "c": "d",
        "a": "a"
        },
        {
        "g": "3",
        "d": "a"
        }
        ]
```

so I guess that Eclipse (as usual) is messing up the logs. :)

---

Why this should be a bug? This is the expected behaviour.

The [toString(int indentSpaces)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString%28int%29) will pretty print, the normal [toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString%28%29) will just output the json. It's also written in the documentation:

> public String toString ()
>
> > Encodes this array as a compact JSON string

and

> public String toString (int indentSpaces)
>
> > Encodes this array as a human readable JSON string for debugging

Comment: Didn't spotted out. Hm.. let me try! :)

Comment: Nope, fine for me. Eclipse fault!

Comment: If it's a replicable error I suggest you to open a tag or send an email to them. :)